# Hive structure not working for nested JSON

Tags: hive

```
{
    "publishTimeStamp": "2017-10-22 09:56:07 -0500",
    "type": [
        {
            "type_no": "111111;",
            "order_no": "1111",
            "release_no": "1",
            "type_no": "487896208",
            "abc": "ups",
            "xyz": "UPSN",
            "order_date": 1508599507000,
            "type_node": "F084",
            "channel": "XYZ",
            "typepadvice_no": "11111",
            "con_no": "180987033",
            "modified_values": {
                "type_no": "1111111"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Please suggest hive structure

Comment: Please put your comment into your question..

Comment: Pleas read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) how to improve your questions.

Answer (score 0):

1) Create a table to load the JSon file.

`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS json_test (Datas STRING);`

2)See that you are able to see the records.

`SELECT * FROM json_test;`

3)Next by making use of the get_json_object we can fetch each record from the json_test table.

`SELECT get_json_object(str,'$.type') AS Type FROM json_test;`

If you want to push the data into a new table that can be also done using `CTAS`.